# Filtering a subdocument in mongoose containing an array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Im trying to return a list of ratings from a given user, filtered by category.

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
...
ratings: [{
  item: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Items' },
  category: String,
  rating: Number
}]
```

If I do the following, I only get the first rating for that category:

```
var query = User.findOne(userId, 'ratings');
query.select({ 'ratings': { $elemMatch: { 'category': req.query.category }}});
```

The following also returns only the first rating:

```
var query = User.find();
query.where({'_id': userId, 'ratings.category': req.query.category});
query.select({ 'ratings.$': 1 });
```

I was able to aggregate the correct results with the following, however, I dont think that'll work since I cant populate after an aggregation.

```
var query = User.aggregate(
  { $match: { _id: userId }},
  { $project: { _id: 1, ratings: 1 }},
  { $unwind: '$ratings' },
  { $match: { 'ratings.category': req.query.category }}
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do the **[population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.populate)** after your aggregation, something like this:

```
var pipeline = [
  { $match: { _id: userId }},
  { $project: { _id: 1, ratings: 1 }},
  { $unwind: '$ratings' },
  { $match: { 'ratings.category': req.query.category } }
];

User.aggregate(pipeline, function (err, result){
    User.populate(result, {path: "ratings.item"}, callback);  
});
```